# Почему класс IdentityUser не доступен в типе проекта .net class library а в консольном приложении он есть?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь имплементировать класс IdentituUser в проекте типа class library, добавил нужный неймспейс, но почему-то его там нету, а когда пытаюсь сделать тоже самое в консольном приложении то всё работает

Comment: Проект с библиотекой подключили? Нужно больше деталей.

Comment: уже решил проблему, добавил зависимость AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore